# How to run a Silverlight xap with fubumvc

Tags: c#, fubumvc

Probably the answer is simple and maybe someone wants to hit me, but obviously I'm stuck right now.

I want to integrate a Silverlight XAP into a fubumvc view page. I am using the HelloWorld sample and enter the following into the page.

```
   <object type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"
    width="700%" height="540">
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="source" value="MyApp.xap" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=124807" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=108181" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight"
            style="border-style: none" />
    </a>
</object>
```

Running this code in a simple html file works fine. The XAP is placed in the same folder as the view page/html file.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. It sounds like you've got it working already. Can you please phrase this in the form of a question?

Comment: My Question is: Why is my Silverlight app running in a simple html page but not running in a view page? What are the mechanisms I am obviously not quite understanding? If I place the SL app in the same folder as the rendered view page, how has the path to the xap file to be constructed?
Hope this question is specific...